# Characters in any game start moving automatically

Tags: axis

Characters in games are running automatically. When I start GTA the character runs forward. When I start Adventure time the camera rotates automatically. Even when I start Unity, start the survival shooter asset and press the play button, it starts to run to the left.

How do I fix this problem?

I'm running on Windows 7, 64 bits.

Comment: It sounds like you have a stuck key on your keyboard.

Comment: ↑↑ or joystick/pad!

Comment: ↑↑ Joystick throttle maybe. Not even stuck, just in a certain position.

Comment: I remove my keyboard and started the game but the same thing hapened.

Comment: Check what inputs the game uses to do the corresponding action and one of them is probably stuck. Did you try to just reboot your system in case its some software fault?

Comment: You mention Unity. Are you running this in a virtual machine? If so, what's your host operating system? What's your virtualization software? If it's Fusion see if changing Preferences>General>Gaming to "Always optimize mouse for games" makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This All was happening due to v joy.
V joy is a software that assign keyboard key to a joystick or game controller button.
There was a error in v joy that constantly send a joystick signal to games.I just uninstalled V joy and restated my computer and the games worked fine.I downloaded v joy last Month to play two player games. That it.